# Division of Arbitrary Long Number

Tags: c++, c++11, division, bigint

I'm creating my own Bigint class in which large numbers, up to 256 digits long, are placed into an array digit by digit. The array is right-aligned, so the smallest digit is in position 255, and the rest is filled with zeroes that are skipped over when the number is output. I've manged to implement ways of handling the addition, subtraction and multiplication of arbitrary large numbers, but I'm lost as to how I would implement division in a similar fashion.

I attempted to use a repeated subtraction method, but it's just way too slow. Is there an optimal method to handle something like this?

Thanks

Comment: How do you do [long division by hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division)?  Implement the same thing in C++.  If you look at the steps at the link, a lot of it is getting the *length* of the number you are dealing with at each step, and then utilizing that in the solution.  If your approach was a naive "keep subtracting until I get to 0", then of course that will be slow.

Comment: I'm not saying that you cannot use at some point the use of the repeated subtraction, but the goal is to *minimize* the usage of it in the overall process.  For example, 683478239472394723 / 52.  You are not going to naively attempt to subtract 52 from that large number so may times.  Instead you would start with the 52 and divide that into 68.  That alone reduces the large integer by 1 digit on the left.

Comment: are you storing digits as ascii '0'-'9' or value 0-9 ?

Comment: Also, when I learned long division as a kid, we didn't write the subanswers in the step ladder you see at the link (and the way it seems to be taught now).  Instead, we wrote the remainder from each subdivision right next to next digit to process and then divided that by the divisor, and so on.  That was effectively the same as the staircase approach, but without the staircase.   Implement that, and you have at most n steps, where n is the number of digits in the dividend, instead of a zillion subtractions.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm, especially the bit "SRT division".